# NodeJS request for Github raw file using token-based authorization results in 404

Tags: node.js, github

I need to read the raw text of a file in my Github private repo so I generated a Personal Access Token and am making a request to the raw version of the file, but get a 404 response code. I've tried a lot of variations of this request code, but always get a 404.

```
const https = require('https');

let options = {}
let url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/account/repo/branch/filename.json';
options.headers = { Authorization: 'token ghp_personal-access-token'}

try {
    let body = await promiseHttpsRequest(url, options);
    let remoteFile = JSON.parse(body);
} catch(err) {
    if (err = 404) throw new Error('This repository requires a token or does not exist. \n ' + url);
    throw err; // 404 ERROR IS THROWN HERE
}

function promiseHttpsRequest(url, options) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        let req = https.request(url, options, res => {
            let body = '';
            res.on('data', data => {body += data});
            res.on('end', function() {
                if (res.statusCode == '200') return resolve(body);
                reject(res.statusCode);
            });
        });
        req.on('error', reject);
        req.end();
    }); 
}
```

When I use cURL to test it, I get the file contents just fine so I know the general token-based approach should work.

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/account/repo/branch/filename.json -H "Authorization: token ghp_personal-access-token"
```

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head against this for a day, I ended up hacking together a `curl` request using `exec()` and it works. It's not an ideal solution, but I need to move on.

I welcome any insight into what I'm doing wrong with the first approach. I'm still new to nodeJS and suspect I'm missing something simple here.